# Build a Key-Value Store

Tags: java, multithreading, file, concurrency

I'm thinking of building a distributed data storage with a client/server architecture. I want the client to associate keys (String) to values (byte[]), like a Map does. I want to do this in Java using sockets, threads and files.

How can i do this as simple as possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it as simple as possible, use [distributed hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table). You can implement your own, of course, but there is no easy way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You really want to reinvent that wheel?

If you're absolutely determined to do this, at least take a look at previous attempts (Cassandra for example is a distributed key-value store written in Java), and see what mistakes were made so you can improve on the effort.

Comment: well I have to It's a project that i have and I realy want to know how to build a simple one.

Comment: Depending on the context, you can almost always replace "Why reinvent the wheel?" with "Please don't compete with me," or "Please don't make me learn something new."